# Python Gensim FastText Saving and Loading Model

Tags: python, gensim, fasttext

I am working with Gensim FASTText modeling and have the following questions.

- The output of "ft_model.save(BASE_PATH + MODEL_PATH + fname)" saves the following 3 files. Is this correct? is there a way to combine all three files?

> ```
> ft_gensim-v3
> ft_gensim-v3.trainables.vectors_ngrams_lockf.npy
> ft_gensim-v3.wv.vectors_ngrams.npy
> ```

When I attempt to load the training file and then use it, I get the following error from `if model.wv.similarity(real_data, labelled['QueryText'][i]) > maxSimilaity:`

> 'function' object has no attribute 'wv'

Finally, both models, is there a way not to have to store the output of `def read_train(path,label_path)` and `def lemmetize(df_col)`so I do not have to run this part of the code every time I want to train the model or compare?

Thanks for the assistance.

**Here is my FastText Train Model**

```
import os
import logging
from config import BASE_PATH, DATA_PATH, MODEL_PATH
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
from pprint import pprint as print
from gensim.models.fasttext import FastText as FT_gensim
from gensim.test.utils import datapath

#Read Training data
import pandas as pd
def read_train(path,label_path):
    d = []
    #e = []
    df = pd.read_excel(path)
    labelled = pd.read_csv(label_path)
    updated_col1 = lemmetize(df['query_text'])
    updated_col2 = lemmetize(labelled['QueryText'])
    for i in range(len(updated_col1)):
        d.append(updated_col1[i])
        #print(d)
    for i in range(len(updated_col2)):
        d.append(updated_col2[i])
    return d


from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import nltk
import string
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

def lemmetize(df_col):
    df_updated_col = pd.Series(0, index = df_col.index)
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    lemmatizer = nltk.stem.wordnet.WordNetLemmatizer()
    ps = PorterStemmer()
    for i, j in zip(df_col, range(len(df_col))):
        lem = []
        t = str(i).lower()
        t = t.replace("'s","")
        t = t.replace("'","")
        translator = str.maketrans(string.punctuation, ' '*len(string.punctuation))
        t = t.translate(translator)
        word_tokens = word_tokenize(t)
        for i in range(len(word_tokens)):
            l1 = lemmatizer.lemmatize(word_tokens[i])
            s1 = ps.stem(word_tokens[i])
            if list(l1) != [''] and list(l1) != [' '] and l1 != '' and l1 != ' ':
                lem.append(l1)
        filtered_sentence = [w for w in lem if not w in stop_words]
        df_updated_col[j] = filtered_sentence
    return df_updated_col

#read test data
def read_test(path):
    return pd.read_excel(path)


#Read labelled data
def read_labelled(path):
    return pd.read_csv(path)


word_tokenized_corpus = read_train('Train Data.xlsx','SMEQueryText.csv')


#Train fasttext model
import tempfile
import os

from gensim.models import FastText
from gensim.test.utils import get_tmpfile
fname = get_tmpfile("ft_gensime-v3")

def train_fastText(data, embedding_size = 60, window_size = 40, min_word = 5, down_sampling = 1e-2, iter=100):
    ft_model = FastText(word_tokenized_corpus,
                      size=embedding_size,
                      window=window_size,
                      min_count=min_word,
                      sample=down_sampling,
                      sg=1,
                      iter=100)

    #with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(prefix=BASE_PATH + MODEL_PATH + 'ft_gensim_v2-', delete=False) as tmp:
    #    ft_model.save(tmp.name, separately=[])
    ft_model.save(BASE_PATH + MODEL_PATH + fname)
    return ft_model


# main function to output
def main(test_path, train_path, labelled):
    test_data = read_test(test_path)
    train_data = read_train(train_path,labelled)
    labelled = read_labelled(labelled)
    output_df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(len(test_data)))
    output_df['test_query'] = str()
    output_df['Similar word'] = str()
    output_df['category'] = str()
    output_df['similarity'] = float()
    model = train_fastText(train_data)

# run main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    output = main('Test Data.xlsx','Train Data.xlsx','QueryText.csv')
```

**Here is my Usage Model**

```
import pandas as pd
from gensim.models import FastText
import gensim
from config import BASE_PATH, DATA_PATH, MODEL_PATH

#Read Training data
def read_train(path,label_path):
    d = []
    #e = []
    df = pd.read_excel(path)
    labelled = pd.read_csv(label_path)
    updated_col1 = lemmetize(df['query_text'])
    updated_col2 = lemmetize(labelled['QueryText'])
    for i in range(len(updated_col1)):
        d.append(updated_col1[i])
    for i in range(len(updated_col2)):
        d.append(updated_col2[i])
    return d

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import nltk
import string
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

def lemmetize(df_col):
    df_updated_col = pd.Series(0, index = df_col.index)
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    lemmatizer = nltk.stem.wordnet.WordNetLemmatizer()
    ps = PorterStemmer()
    for i, j in zip(df_col, range(len(df_col))):
        lem = []
        t = str(i).lower()
        t = t.replace("'s","")
        t = t.replace("'","")
        translator = str.maketrans(string.punctuation, ' '*len(string.punctuation))
        t = t.translate(translator)
        word_tokens = word_tokenize(t)
        for i in range(len(word_tokens)):
            l1 = lemmatizer.lemmatize(word_tokens[i])
            s1 = ps.stem(word_tokens[i])
            if list(l1) != [''] and list(l1) != [' '] and l1 != '' and l1 != ' ':
                lem.append(l1)
        filtered_sentence = [w for w in lem if not w in stop_words]
        df_updated_col[j] = filtered_sentence
    return df_updated_col

#read test data
def read_test(path):
    return pd.read_excel(path)

#Read labelled data
def read_labelled(path):
    return pd.read_csv(path)

def load_training():
    return FT_gensim.load(BASE_PATH + MODEL_PATH +'ft_gensim-v3')

#compare similarity
def compare_similarity(model, real_data, labelled):
    maxWord = ''
    category = ''
    maxSimilaity = 0
    #print("train data",labelled[1])
    for i in range(len(labelled)):
        if model.similarity(real_data, labelled['QueryText'][i]) > maxSimilaity:
            #print('labelled',labelled['QueryText'][i], 'i', i)
            maxWord = labelled['QueryText'][i]
            category = labelled['Subjectmatter'][i]
            maxSimilaity = model.similarity(real_data, labelled['QueryText'][i])

    return maxWord, category, maxSimilaity

# Output from Main to excel
from pandas import ExcelWriter
def export_Excel(data, aFile = 'FASTTEXTOutput.xlsx'):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    writer = ExcelWriter(aFile)
    df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
    writer.save()

# main function to output
def main(test_path, train_path, labelled):
    test_data = read_test(test_path)
    train_data = read_train(train_path,labelled)
    labelled = read_labelled(labelled)
    output_df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(len(test_data)))
    output_df['test_query'] = str()
    output_df['Similar word'] = str()
    output_df['category'] = str()
    output_df['similarity'] = float()
    model = load_training
    for i in range(len(test_data)):
        output_df['test_query'][i] = test_data['query_text'][i]
        #<first change>
        maxWord, category, maxSimilaity = compare_similarity(model, str(test_data['query_text'][i]), labelled)
        output_df['Similar word'][i] = maxWord
        output_df['category'][i] = category
        output_df['similarity'][i] = maxSimilaity
    #<second change>    
    return output_df

# run main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    output = main('Test Data.xlsx','Train Data.xlsx','SMEQueryText.csv')
    export_Excel(output)
```

**Here is the full tracible error message**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-57803b59c0b9> in <module>
      1 # run main
      2 if __name__ == "__main__":
----> 3     output = main('Test Data.xlsx','Train Data.xlsx','SMEQueryText.csv')
      4     export_Excel(output)

<ipython-input-21-17cb88ee0f79> in main(test_path, train_path, labelled)
     13         output_df['test_query'][i] = test_data['query_text'][i]
     14         #<first change>
---> 15         maxWord, category, maxSimilaity = compare_similarity(model, str(test_data['query_text'][i]), labelled)
     16         output_df['Similar word'][i] = maxWord
     17         output_df['category'][i] = category

<ipython-input-19-84d7f268d669> in compare_similarity(model, real_data, labelled)
      6     #print("train data",labelled[1])
      7     for i in range(len(labelled)):
----> 8         if model.wv.similarity(real_data, labelled['QueryText'][i]) > maxSimilaity:
      9             #print('labelled',labelled['QueryText'][i], 'i', i)
     10             maxWord = labelled['QueryText'][i]

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'wv'
```

Comment: It might be easier to debug if you posted the full traceback of your error message as well

Comment: I have added the full error message to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got three separate, only-vaguely-related questions here. Taking each in order:

- Why are there 3 files, and can they be combined?

It's more efficient to store the big raw arrays separately from the main 'pickled' model – and for models above a few gigabytes in size, necessary to work-around 'pickle' implementation limits. So I'd recommend just keeping the default behavior, and keeping the habit of managing/moving/copying the sets of files together.

If your model is small enough, there is something you can try, though. The `.save()` method has an optional parameter `sep_limit` which controls the threshold array size, over which arrays are stored as separate files. By setting that much larger, say `sep_limit=2*1024*1024*1024` (2GiB), smaller models should save a single file. (But, loading will be slower, you won't have the sometimes-useful option of memory-map loading, and saving may break on oversized models.)

- Why is there a `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'wv'` error?

Your line of code `model = load_training` assigns an actual function to the `model` variable, rather than what you probably intended, the return-value of calling that function with some arguments. That function has no `.wv` attribute, hence the error. If `model` were an actual instance of `FastText`, you'd not get that error.

- Can the corpus text be stored to avoid repeat preprocessing and conversion from pandas formats?

Sure, you can just write the text to a file. Roughly:

```py
with open('mycorpus.txt', mode='w') as corpusfile:
    for text in word_tokenized_corpus:
        corpusfile.write(' '.join(text))
        corpusfile.write('\n')
```

Though in fact, `gensim` offers a utility function, `utils.save_as_line_sentence()`, that can do this (& explicitly handles some extra encoding concerns). See:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/utils.html#gensim.utils.save_as_line_sentence

The `LineSentence` utility class in `gensim.models.word2vec` can stream texts from such a file back for future re-use:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.LineSentence

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  And yes, the questions are not really related to each other but I didn't want to ask three different questions. For the ArributeError function.  How can I pass model as an actual instance of FastText?

Comment: If you want to execute the `load_training` function, rather than refer to the function itself, there need to be trailing parens: `load_training()`. (Then, the code will run, it will return the `FastText` instance it's created, and `model` will receive that value.)

Comment: I can't believe that I overlooked that simple mistake.  Thank you so very much.

Comment: Happens to us all! Getting a 2nd set of eyes (as with a question here), taking a breather then combing over the code fresh, or adding lots of prints/asserts around the unexpected behavior, to verify where things diverge from what you're assuming (eg finding the first place `model` doesn't have `.wv`) are all classic ways to catch those glitches.